# SimpleStatement as CQL

Tags: java, cassandra, cql, datastax-java-driver

I am trying to transform a `SimpleStatement` to CQL.

```java
RegularInsert regularStatement = ...;

Map<String, Object> namedValues = new HashMap<>();
namedValues.put("a", "Hello");
namedValues.put("b", 1);

SimpleStatement statement = regularStatement.build(namedValues);

System.out.println(statement.getQuery());
System.out.println(statement.getNamedValues());  // Map<CqlIdentifier, Object>
```

Returns:

```
INSERT INTO keyspace.table (a,b) VALUES (?,?)
{a=Hello, b=1}
```

Which is fine, but I **also** need the final CQL query:

```
INSERT INTO keyspace.table (a,b) VALUES ('Hello',1)
```

I tried to bind named values to `RegularInsert` first, which I can use to get the CQL raw string with `asCql()`, and then build a `SimpleStatement`. But it is not working as I expected:

```
RegularInsert regularStatement = statementInsertWithKeyspace(database.getDatabaseName());

// Transform <String> to literal <Term>
Map<String, Term> literalNamedValues = namedValues.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> literal(e.getValue())));

regularStatement = regularStatement.values(literalNamedValues);

System.out.println(regularStatement.asCql());

SimpleStatement statement = regularStatement.values(literalNamedValues).build();

System.out.println(statement.getQuery());
System.out.println(statement.getNamedValues());  // Map<CqlIdentifier, Object>
```

Returns:

```
INSERT INTO keyspace.table (a,b) VALUES ('Hello',1)
INSERT INTO keyspace.table (a,b) VALUES ('Hello',1)
{}
```

How can I get the raw CQL from `SimpleStatement`, while preserving the CQL template (without values)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diving into, it seems that one Statement doesn't hold the bound value AND the template. The Values come from an ImmutableMap which means, once you `build()` the query or set the `values()`, the "?" get irrevokably replaced by the actual values. So if you need both 'at once', then your best bet seems to be using two Statement-Objects, one bound and one unbound.

```
RegularInsert regularStatement = ...;

Map<String, Object> namedValues = new HashMap<>();
namedValues.put("a", "Hello");
namedValues.put("b", 1);

// both build() and values() create new Objects
SimpleStatement statement = regularStatement.build(namedValues);
String boundStatement = regularStatement.values(namedValues).asCql();

System.out.println(statement.getQuery());
System.out.println(statement.getNamedValues());  // Map<CqlIdentifier, Object>
System.out.println(boundStatement);
```